# Data not added to firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have a VueJS application and a firebase project, I'm trying to access the realtime database to add data to it but it's not working and it's not logging anything.
I have a firebase.js file :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "myapp",
  authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "myapp",
  storageBucket: "myapp",
  messagingSenderId: "myapp",
  appId: "myapp"
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebaseApp;
```

And i have this create user method in a file called DataService.js :

```
import firebase from "../firebase";
import 'firebase/compat/database';
const db = firebase.database();

create(user) {
        db.ref('users' + user.login).set({
          username: user.login,
          email: user.password,
          profile_picture : false
        },(error)=>{
          if(error){
            console.log(error)
          }else{
            console.log('all good');
          }
        });
      }
```

In my component, I have a method called SaveUser that i'm calling in the submit

```
saveuser(){
        var data = {
        login: this.login,
        password: this.password,
        isvalid: false
        };
        DataService.create(data);
        },
```

What am I doing wrong ? I'm new to firebase and I don't really know what's not working

Answer (score 0):

Your `firebaseConfig` variable is missing a `databaseURL` property, which is pretty much the only key that is required for your code to be able to find the Realtime Database on the server. So add that key/value, and try again.

Comment: Yes I added it but it's still not working